# Negation handling in NLP

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, text-processing

I'm currently working on a project, where I want to extract emotion from text. As I'm using conceptnet5 (a semantic network), I can't however simply prefix words in a sentence that contains a negation-word, as those words would simply not show up in conceptnet5's API.

Here's an example:

> The movie wasn't that good.

Hence, I figured that I could use wordnet's lemma functionality to replace adjectives in sentences that contain negation-words like (not, ...).

In the previous example, the algorithm would detect `wasn't` and would replace it with `was not`.
Further, it would detect a negation-word `not`, and replace `good` with it's antonym `bad`.
The sentence would read:

> The movie was that bad.

While I see that this isn't the most elegant way, and it does probably in many cases produce the wrong result, I'd still like to handle negation that way as I frankly don't know any better approach.

**Considering my problem:**
Unfortunately, I did not find any library that would allow me to replace all occurrences of appended negation-words (`wasn't` => `was not`).
I mean I could do it manually, by replacing the occurrences with a regex, but then I would be stuck with the english language.

Therefore I'd like to ask if some of you know a library, function or **better method** that could help me here.
Currently I'm using python `nltk`, still it doesn't seem that it contains such functionality, but I may be wrong.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Cases like `wasn't` can be simply parsed by tokenization (`tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)`): `wasn't` will turn into `was` and `n't`.

But negative meaning can also be formed by 'Quasi negative words, like hardly, barely, seldom' and 'Implied negatives, such as fail, prevent, reluctant, deny, absent', look into [this paper](http://www.academypublication.com/issues/past/tpls/vol03/07/17.pdf). Even more detailed analysis can be found in Christopher Potts' [On the negativity of negation](https://web.stanford.edu/~cgpotts/papers/potts-salt20-negation.pdf)
.

Considering your initial problem, sentiment analysis, most modern approaches, as far as I know, don't process negations explicitly; instead, they use supervised approaches with high-order n-grams. Those actually processing negation usually append special prefix NOT_ to all words between negation and punctuation marks.

Comment: Hi! I was wondering if this was stull the case that most modern approaches don't process negations explicitly?